# Как сделать адаптивные кнопки?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать адапативные кнопки, при увеличении размера экрана, все кнопки разлетаются. Вот код

```css
.body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-space {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.save_button {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
}

div.btn-group.btn-lgg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-lg {
  width: 362px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-lgg {
  width: 179px;
  height: 60px;
}

.btn-lggg {
  width: 222.47px;
  height: 46px;
}

.btn-lgggg {
  width: 222.47px;
  height: 41px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-indent: 0.1em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

div>hr {
  width: 125px;
  height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}

.gray {
  color: gray;
  /* Цвет символа */
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.price {
  color: gray;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
    $(function() {
      $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row" style="margin-left:-10px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <form>
          <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Страна, курорт или отель" style="  width: 276px;height: 60px;" data-toggle="dropdown" autofocus>
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="margin-left:-275px;font-size:18px;color:#059bce;"></i>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox">Все курорты, Турция</li>
            <div>
              <hr>
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Популярные курорты</h6>
              <hr>
            </div>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"> Аланья,<span class="gray">Турция</span></div>
                <div class="right"><span class="price">от 17 701 р./чел.</span></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"> Анталья,<span class="gray">Турция</span></div>
                <div class="right"><span class="price">от 18 609 р./чел.</span></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"> Белек,<span class="gray">Турция</span></div>
                <div class="right"><span class="price">от 37 896 р./чел.</span></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Бодрум,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"> Кемер,<span class="gray">Турция</span></div>
                <div class="right"><span class="price">от 15 401 р./чел.</span></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Мармарис,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"> Сиде,<span class="gray">Турция</span></div>
                <div class="right"><span class="price">от 19 959 р./чел.</span></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <div>
              <hr>
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Остальные курорты</h6>
              <hr>
            </div>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Анкара,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Даламан,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Дидим,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Каппадокия,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Кушадасы,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Манавгат,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Мугла,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Олюдениз,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Памуккале,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Саригерме,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Стамбул,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Фетхие,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Финике,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Чешме,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Эрджияс,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--
  -->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lgg" style="margin-left:-60px;data-toggle=" dropdown ">
      <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt "style="margin-left:-140px;font-size:22px;color:#059bce; ""></i>
     </button>
      </div>
      <!--
    -->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lgg" data-toggle="dropdown">Test 3</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--
-->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lgg" data-toggle="dropdown">Test 3</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2" style="margin-left:-41.5%; margin-top:-6.0%;margin:display;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group" <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white  btn-lgggg" data-toggle="dropdown">Город вылета: </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width:280px;" role="City">
          <li><a href="#">Москва</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Абакан</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Астрахань</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Барнаул</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Белгород</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Благовещенск</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Брянск</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Владивосток</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Владикавказ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Волгоград</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Воронеж</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Екатеринбург</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новосибирск</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Нальчик</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Мурманск</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Нижний Новгород</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lgggg" style="margin-left:610px; margin-top:-65px;">Горящие туры <span class="tab-search-hot-tours-discount">-50%</span></button>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: что должно получится? сейчас вообще ничего не понятно

Comment: Дополню скринами, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: Обновил, вот что происходит при увеличении или уменьшении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно ничего не понятно, но вот пример кода, чтобы кнопки были адаптивными, надеюсь помог.

```
<div class="flex">
    <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

СSS:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Сами кнопки, думаю вы сами стилизуете, а вот пример как работают флексбоксы, чтобы кнопки, при изменении ширины экрана становились друг за другом, можете для удобства каждую кнопку обернуть в `div`. К сожалению полный ответ тяжело дать, так как структура `html` не очень правильная, а так цель задачи была выполнена.

Comment: То что мне нужно, спасибо.

Comment: На здоровье :))